# How can I set node positions in a hierarchical layout?

Tags: vis.js, vis.js-network

I have a network drawn by vis.js in hierarchical fashion (top-down). I can call `getPositions` to retrieve any node's X coordinate after moving nodes left and right with mouse interaction, but when I call `storePositions` the nodes are moved back to their original positions, where they were drawn when first added to the `Network`.

I am looking to have the user be able to control the position of each node in its "free" axis of movement (i.e., in a top-down hierarchical layout, node `y` positions are set by `node.level`, but node `x` positions are set by user interaction and remain persistent)

Comment: I have found that I have desynchronized the Node from the Dataset it is based on. The Node, from which Vis.js is drawing the graph, has the `x` and `y` fields set by the Hierarchical layout algorithm, while my Dataset holds the `x` and `y` values I really want. See attached: [browser object log](https://imgur.com/a/OguaSKA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of edits to LayoutEngine.js solved this. Mostly so I don't forget: `LayoutEngine::setupHierarchicalLayout` can be patched to resync the Node in question with its x or y values in the Dataset.

Inside `LayoutEngine::setupHierarchicalLayout`, one can set `this.body.nodes[nodeId].x` or `this.body.nodes[nodeId].y` to their desired location.

See also:

[Vis.js pull request #4183](https://github.com/almende/vis/pull/4183)